# Apache Flink: Using a BroadcastStream for an infinite amount of values

Tags: java, join, state, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink newbie here, currently trying to implement a Flink job that performs a logic such as the following query

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM EVENT_C c
 WHERE c.exclusion_id NOT IN (
    SELECT s.exclusion_id
      FROM EVENT_S s
      JOIN EVENT_A a
        ON s.input_id = a.input_id
     WHERE a.tags = 'some-value'
 )
```

So far I've successfully assembled most of the logic. Each `Event` is handled as a separate DataStream. Then I use a JoinFunction with a TimeWindow to perform the EVENT_S + EVENT_A join.

The challenge is performing the `NOT IN` part of the logic.
Currently I am trying to use a `BroadcastStream` for the `exclusion_id` values that were collected on the tumbling window. Then I'll broadcast these values into a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` that will receive both the `EVENT_C` records and the `exclusion_id` values.

```java
// Join EventS with EventA, broadcast the results
BroadcastStream<String> exclusionIdBroadcastStream = sStream
        .join(aStream)
        .where(new KeySelector<EventS, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object getKey(EventS value) throws Exception {
                return value.getInputId();
            }
        })
        .equalTo(new KeySelector<EventA, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object getKey(EventA value) throws Exception {
                return value.getInputId();
            }
        })
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
        .apply(new JoinFunction<EventS, EventA, String>() {
            @Override
            public String join(EventS first, EventA second) throws Exception {
                return first.getTurnId();
            }
        })
        .broadcast(turnIdStateDescriptor);

// Process EventC by performing a NOT IN with the broadcast ids
cStream
        .keyBy(new KeySelector<EventC, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(EventC value) throws Exception {
                return value.getUniqueId();
            }
        })
        .connect(exclusionIdBroadcastStream)
        .process(new EventFilterBroadcastProcessFunction())
        .addSink(s3Sink);
```

This is the ProcessFunction implementation, which caches the EventC record and sets an EventTime timer to perform the filtering.

```java
public class EventFilterBroadcastProcessFunction extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<String, EventC, String, OutputEvent> {

    private static final MapStateDescriptor<String, String> BROADCAST_DESCRIPTOR =
            new MapStateDescriptor<>("ExclusuionIdBroadcastState", BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);

    private static final ListStateDescriptor<EventC> EVENT_C_DESCRIPTOR =
            new ListStateDescriptor<EventC>("CustomerIdEvents", TypeInformation.of(EventC.class));

    private transient ListState<EventC> eventsToReprocessState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        this.eventsToReprocessState = this.getRuntimeContext().getListState(EVENT_C_DESCRIPTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(EventC event, ReadOnlyContext context, Collector<OutputEvent> out) throws Exception {
        final String turnId = context.getBroadcastState(BROADCAST_DESCRIPTOR).get(event.getTurnId());
        final long expirationTimestamp = nextTimeoutWindow(context.timestamp(), Time.minutes(1));

        if (turnId == null) {
            // Maybe the event is safe to collect, or the turnId has not been broadcast yet. Save it for later.
            this.eventsToReprocessState.add(event);

            context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(expirationTimestamp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void processBroadcastElement(String turnId, Context context, Collector<OutputEvent> out) throws Exception {
        context.getBroadcastState(BROADCAST_DESCRIPTOR).put(turnId, turnId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<OutputEvent> out) throws Exception {
        super.onTimer(timestamp, ctx, out);
        int count = 0;
        int size = 0;
        final Iterable<EventC> eventsToReprocess = this.eventsToReprocessState.get();
        if (eventsToReprocess != null) {
            for (EventC event: eventsToReprocess) {
                size++;
                if (!ctx.getBroadcastState(BROADCAST_DESCRIPTOR).contains(event.getTurnId())) {
                    final OutputEvent OutputEvent = generateOutputEvent(event);
                    out.collect(OutputEvent);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            eventsToReprocessState.clear();
        }

    }

    private OutputEvent generateOutputEvent(final EventC event) {
        return OutputEvent.builder()
                ...
                .build();
    }

    public static long nextTimeoutWindow(final long timestamp, final Time interval) {
        return endOfWindow(timestamp, interval) + interval.toMilliseconds();
    }

    public static long beginningOfWindow(final long timestamp, final Time interval) {
        return timestamp - (timestamp % interval.toMilliseconds());
    }

    public static long endOfWindow(final long timestamp, final Time interval) {
        return beginningOfWindow(timestamp, interval) + interval.toMilliseconds();
    }
```

We are experimenting with a BroadcastStream because we can treat `exclusion_id` as a rule, and increase the parallelism of this task by having all parallel executions perform the `NOT IN` over the same set of rules. The problem with this approach is that Broadcast state is read-only, meaning it will only grow over time, and I cannot remove items from the map. This causes the snapshots to grow over time, and CPU usage also increases due to the state becoming larger. Also Broadcast state is kept on Heap, so memory usage also increases over time.

Is there any way to clean the broadcast state when the `onTimer` method fires ?
Or is there a better strategy to achieve such a "join/not in" logic instead of using a Broadcast function?

Currently using **Flink v1.11** over Kinesis Data Analytics, running on **JDK 11**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can take the output of the join and send it through a `ProcessFunction` with state, where you forward the join result as a regular event, and create a timer based on some TTL value. When the timer fires, you send out a retraction (deletion) event.

This stream is then broadcast, and you can use it to update the broadcast state used in the subsequent filtering operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I ended up moving away from the Broadcast pattern and using a combination of JoinFunction (for the A + S streams) and a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` for the filtering between the exclusion list and the C stream, partitioning both inputs by `exclusion_id`. This way, whenever I got events for both inputs, no output is produced. Same happens if I only got `exclusion_id` events, no outputs. If I got events for C, and not for the exclusion, then no matches were found, and every C event is an output.